# Ionic spinner within button vertical alignment

Tags: ionic-framework

I have tried to implement a [spinner](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSpinner/) within a button but for some reason the spinner seems to be top aligned instead of vertically centered:
[image]

My code is the following:

```
<button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">
<ion-spinner class="spinner-energized"></ion-spinner> Click me!
</button>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjOqvK?editors=1010

Any idea why?

Comment: did you every solve this?

Comment: nope. not yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ionic team offered the following solution:

```
.spinner svg {
  width: 16px !important;
  height: 16px !important;
}
```

[New codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqeYRQ)

They gave me a bit more context:

> This was not the intended use for ion-spinner, so custom css is
>   needed. You need to adjust the width/height.

Comment: The intended use is, I guess, to be used in $ionLoading, but what if we don't want a single spinner for the whole page? SPAs don't work like that, generally.

Answer (score 3):

You can also solve this using flexbox as so:

```
<button class="button button-light">
    <div class="center-vertical-horizontal">
      Button text
      <ion-spinner class="button-spinner"></ion-spinner>
    </div>
</button>
```

And the following css:

```
.center-vertical-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.button-spinner {
  display: flex;
}
```

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRVgGK

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem.I solve like this.

```
 <html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
       .spinner svg {
   padding-top: 2px;
  width: 38px;
 height: 38px;
 stroke: #fff;
  fill: #999;
 }
.button-text {
 vertical-align:text-bottom;
}
 </style>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

<script id="templates/event-menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">

    <ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>

        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
          <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
          </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
      </ion-nav-bar>

      <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content> 


</script>

<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Welcome">
    <ion-content class="padding">

      <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">   <ion-spinner class="spinner-energized"></ion-spinner><span class="button-text">Click me!</span></button>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
 </script>
```

Comment: When I added your CSS to my codepen example it still does not work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGNvPr Any idea why?

Comment: its works on codepen.I cannot paste in stackoverflow .sorry for misspellings. http://codepen.io/nazrdogan_/pen/LNqeWx?editors=1010